# what more I need to can storage in redis cache in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis, session-state

I was installed XX from nuget and **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName**, also put the next configuration in the web.config **RedisSessionStateProvider**

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider"  cookieless="true" > <providers> <add name="RedisSessionProvider"  type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" port="6380" host="XXX.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="OQm………15E=" ssl="true" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="3000" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" /></providers>
```

but can't storage the session on redis, but if I do the connection on code, it is succesfull. my code:

/// set the conecction

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
    var redisOption = new ConfigurationOptions();

    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("XXX.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=OQmAPmp0 . . . . TJE15E=");

});


///return connection object

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
{
    get
    {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
} 

///the session is created and added some elements manually in redis to test     

public ActionResult SessionStart()
{
    IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
    Session["loginTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    string strValue = "myvalue";
    Session.Add("myvalue ", strValue);
    return View();
}
```

I need storage the session automatically in redis, please help me!

Comment: Do you get an error at all?

Comment: only cannot store the session value on redis cache automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was reinstall the packages RedisSessionStateProvider and StackExchange.Redis.StrongName from nuget, after that is need change some things in the web config

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" >
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore"
     type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
     host="abcde1234.redis.cache.windows.net"
     accessKey="FuDmzfO3B/6M1cX1ls="
     ssl="true" throwOnError="true" port="6380" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"
     databaseId = "1"
     />
 </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**CONTROLLER**

And then only create a session object:

```
Session["test-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()] = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

You can use [Redis Desktop Manager](http://redisdesktop.com/) for tracking the values or the Azure portal
[image]

the solution was gave by @juank.

@Luca Detomi you can review the answer

Answer (score 1):

It can't be that automatic, your need one more extra library to marry Redis and ASP.NET, and a small web.config modification. For example, the following shall do if you are not tied to StackExchange.Redis
https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore, or this uses StackExchange.Redis as in your case https://github.com/welegan/RedisSessionProvider